# How to apply a function to factored subgroups in R?

Tags: r, function, intersection

I have some columns of characters as a data frame df:

```
V1 V2 V3 group
B  C  -  1
B  C  C  1
B  C  C  1
A  C  A  2
A  A  A  2
A  A  A  2
```

I would like to find out whether the intersection of the factored groups for each column are empty or not and would like to output the result in say a TRUE/FALSE format.

Column 2 is the only column with non-zero intersection which I have checked using:

```
> is.na(intersect(df[,2][df$group=="1"],df[,2][df$group=="2"]))
[1] FALSE
```

I was trying to automate this for the three columns V1-V3 using

```
by(df[,1:3], df$group, function(x) { is.na(intersect(x[df$group=="1"],x[df$group=="2"]))})
```

but got an error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, df$group == "2") : undefined columns selected
```

Thanks for any suggestions/alternatives!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 lapply(df[,1:3], function(x)
           is.na(intersect(x[df$group=='1'], x[df$group=='2'])))
```

Or

```
 Map(function(x,y) is.na(intersect(x,y)),
            df[df$group=='1',-4], df[df$group=='2', -4])
```

If you have many `groups`,

```
 lapply(df[,1:3], function(x) is.na(Reduce(`intersect`,split(x, df$group))))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A"), V2 = c("C", 
"C", "C", "C", "A", "A"), V3 = c("-", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A"
), group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
"V3", "group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```